# Wordpress functions.php not returning results via shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a little trouble getting the following code (added to theme's functions.php) to return results to a post when using the shortcode.

Here is the code I put in functions.php:

```
<?php

function foo_shortcode(){

    global $wpdb; 

    $r = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
                *
                FROM 
                    shows_16 c
                WHERE
                    c.status = 1
                GROUP BY
                    c.id
                ORDER BY
                    c.date_start ASC");

    $c1= '<div id="main-wrapper">   

        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr id="r1">
                    <td id="thead" colspan="4">EVENTS 2016</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="r2">
                    <td id="c1" >Date</td>
                    <td id="c2" >Event</td>
                    <td id="c3" >City</td>
                    <td id="c4" >Details</td>
                </tr>';

    foreach ($r as $show_result) {


        $c2 .= '<tr id="rx" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"><td id="x1"><meta itemprop="startDate" content="' . 
            $show_result["date_start"] . '">' . date('M j', strtotime($show_result['date_start'])) .
            (($show_result["date_start"] != $show_result["date_end"]) ? print ' - ' . 
            '<meta itemprop="endDate" content="'. $show_result["date_end"].'">' . 
            date('M j', strtotime($show_result["date_end"])) : "") . '</td><td id="x2">' . 
            ($show_result['url']=='') ? print '<span itemprop="name">'.$show_result["name"].
            '</span>' : print '<a itemprop="url" href="' . $show_result["url"] . 
            '" target="_blank"><span itemprop="name">'. $show_result["name"] . 
            '</span></a>') . '</td> <td id="x3" itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">'. 
            $show_result["city"] . '</span></td> <td id="x4" itemprop="description">' .  
            $show_result["details"]. '</td></tr>';

    }


    $c3 = '</tbody></table></div>';

    $c4 = $c1.$c2.$c3;

    return $c4;
}


add_shortcode('foo_sc', 'foo_shortcode');

?>
```

Then I use the following shortcode in the Wordpress post:

```
[foo_sc]
```

The results I am expecting are a table populated with events kind of like this:

```
Jan 3   The Foo Event   Bar-city    Foo's Event details go here
Jan 4   The Bar Event   Foo-city    Bar's Event details go here
...
```

I have the table "shows_16" set up in the wordpress database and it contains valid data.

The function is returning the results from $c1, $c3 but not $c2.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you check your query and does it show results when you try it in phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes - I just tested it now and it returns the expected result set from the table

Comment: please check my answer that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your **`$c2`** variable is not properly initialize and is not accessible outside your loop the solution might be to initialize it above your loop like this

```
$c2 ="";
foreach ($r as $show_result) {


        $c2 .= '<tr id="rx" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"><td id="x1"><meta itemprop="startDate" content="' . 
            $show_result["date_start"] . '">' . date('M j', strtotime($show_result['date_start'])) .
            (($show_result["date_start"] != $show_result["date_end"]) ? print ' - ' . 
            '<meta itemprop="endDate" content="'. $show_result["date_end"].'">' . 
            date('M j', strtotime($show_result["date_end"])) : "") . '</td><td id="x2">' . 
            ($show_result['url']=='') ? print '<span itemprop="name">'.$show_result["name"].
            '</span>' : print '<a itemprop="url" href="' . $show_result["url"] . 
            '" target="_blank"><span itemprop="name">'. $show_result["name"] . 
            '</span></a>') . '</td> <td id="x3" itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">'. 
            $show_result["city"] . '</span></td> <td id="x4" itemprop="description">' .  
            $show_result["details"]. '</td></tr>';

    }


    $c3 = '</tbody></table></div>';

    $c4 = $c1.$c2.$c3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is an ooooold question, but here's my answer. :D

If you expect your output to be long, it's a better idea to use ob_start() and ob_get_clean() instead of simply storing strings in variables.

ob_start(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

ob_get_clean(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

This should function something like this:

```
ob_start();?>

//...create your HTML...
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
```